# Can I use anchor tags to jump to different locations on different pages in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I'm using anchor tags in my navbar to send users to different sections on the about page. Problem is, it only works if I'm already in the about page. It doesn't jump to the specific location I want it to when I click on those links in my navbar from other pages (like for example, homepage).

This is my `navbar.html`:

```
      <mat-menu #aboutMenu="matMenu">
        <button mat-menu-item>
          <a href="/about-us#about"> About </a>
        </button>
        <button mat-menu-item>
          <a href="/about-us#token"> Token </a>
        </button>
        <button mat-menu-item>
          <a href="/about-us#team"> Team </a>
        </button>
      </mat-menu>
```

And this is my `about.html`:

```
    <a name="about">
      <h1>About</h1>
    </a>
     .
     .
     .
    <a name="token">
      <h2>Token Details</h2>
    </a>
     .
     .
    <a name="team">Team Members</a>
```

Comment: `<a href="/about.html#token"> Token </a>` and  `<a id="token">` can be done for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it with the help of [@davimargelo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12777161/davimargelo)'s answer like this:

`navbar.html`

```
        <button
          mat-menu-item
          [routerLink]="'/about-us'"
          fragment="token"
          (click)="onAnchorClick()"
          class="button__mat--menu"
        >
          <a href="/about-us#token"> Token </a>
        </button>
```

`navbar.ts`

```
  onAnchorClick() {
    this.route.fragment.subscribe((f) => {
      const element = document.querySelector('#' + f);
      if (element) element.scrollIntoView(true);
    });
  }
```

`about-us.html`

```
    <a name="token">
      <h2 id="token-details">Token Details</h2>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved using the following code:

.html:

```
<a [routerLink]="'/about-us'" fragment="about" (click)="onAnchorClick()"> About </a>
```

.ts:

```
  onAnchorClick ( ) {
    this.route.fragment.subscribe ( f => {
      const element = document.querySelector ( "#" + f )
      if ( element ) element.scrollIntoView ( true )
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate to another page on clicking a button just use angular event binding syntax.The event binding listens to the click event of the button and calls its respective method in the component.ts file.
Refer link for more understanding:
https://angular.io/guide/event-binding